# Responsive Resizing of a Paragraph With An Inline Image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Had this issue for a couple of days now and haven't been able to work my way around it. I am building a desktop-first responsive webpage where I have a paragraph element and an image element placed side-by-side, the idea being to make it look like one item, the paragraph taking up 30% and the image taking up the remaining 70% of the container with a border-radius on the paragraph's left top/left bottom and the image's right top/right bottom. Now, obviously with differing screen sizes there is only one size where the height of these elements is equal. As soon as you resize it further from this point the height increases or decreases for both elements.

Originally I wanted to keep them both the same height until the 1024px breakpoint, where I will make them block elements again, although I don't know if this is possible due to the resizing nature of the paragraph. If anyone has any ideas on how to make these look more presentable that would be great. I may have gone about my idea completely the wrong way, but if someone could take the time to help me out here I would be very appreciative. I've been trying everything for the past couple of days to no prevail!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
  <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

   <div class="container">
   <section class="home-main">    
     <p class="main-para">aliquip sunt aut efflorescere fore praesentibus tamen quae eram officia 
       illustriora est tempor o id quis adipisicing appellat sed multos ea lorem 
       sempiternum qui doctrina ab dolor senserit tractavissent an probant 
       instituendarum elit culpa qui magna tempor aliquip quamquam minim voluptate 
       legam arbitrantur graviterque eu</p>  
      <img class="main-image" src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
    </section>        
  </div>

</body>

</html>


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

/*  HOME-MAIN
============================================= */

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .main-para {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    padding: 2em 1em 2.15em;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    border-top-left-radius: 1em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
  }

  .main-image {
    border-top-right-radius: 1em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
    float: right;
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```

Comment: the questions is, how do you make the two elements have the same size even when you're resizing the page? is this correct?

Comment: Yeah I get you...I think it'll be far easier to leave them as block-level elements and stop trying to do fancy things.

Comment: Please check my answer below if I understood your problem correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, you want to keep the ratio between the placeholder (your image) and the text at 70/30. First, just remove the `max-width:80%` from the container class so that when you resize the viewport it does not look crammed on mobile.

```
.container {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Then add `display: flex` and other selectors as shown below so that the elements wrap nicely into the flex, serving in essence as a wrapper:

```
.home-main {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: nowrap; 
}
```

Finally, give a bit of margin and padding to the text box and set the width of your image to 70% of the outer container:

```
.main-para {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

img {
  max-width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

[Get the plunk here](https://plnkr.co/edit/m4vREp6o1QPBapjvqjQK?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily by [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Basically, you ask Flexbox (nicely) to fit children elements inside a parent element with certain conditions like "I want child A to always be this big, while child B covers all the remaining space. Oh and make them stack. Sometimes." Something like that.

Flexbox also removes the pesky hack of using `float`s.

[Pen here.](https://codepen.io/reiallenramos/pen/XZjmye)

I changed only the `@media` queries in your CSS from this:

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .main-para {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    padding: 2em 1em 2.15em;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    border-top-left-radius: 1em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
  }

  .main-image {
    border-top-right-radius: 1em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
    float: right;
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```

to this

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .home-main{
    display: flex; /* NEW */
  }
  .main-para {
    flex: 4; /* NEW */
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    padding: 2em 1em 2.15em;
    margin: 0 0; /* NEW */
    border-top-left-radius: 1em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
  }

  .main-image {
    border-top-right-radius: 1em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
    flex: 6; /* NEW */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made something for you, but i don't think it's a good idea, because, resizing an img will not look very good, but you can give it a try.

i removed the media queries and added a height to both p class and img class, and added font-size : 1em; to the text, here's a jsfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/3L9sLp9v/

```
.main-para {
   float: left;
   width: 40%;
   background-color: #000;
   color: #fff;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   font-size: 1.4em;
   padding: 2em 1em 2.15em;
   margin: 0 0 1em;
   border-top-left-radius: 1em;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
   font-size: 1em;
   height: 325px;
}

.main-image {
   border-top-right-radius: 1em;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
   float: right;
   width: 60%;
   height: 325px;
}
```